# Stopping a point cache bake

Tags: interface, baking, point-clouds

I have a problem with blender sometimes: when I am running a simulation bake of some kinds, i.e. the point cache bakes, Blender will not allow you to interact with the interface at all. This is not the case with fluid bakes, but with just about every other bake. Cloth, soft-body, particles, rigid-bodies, etc. Is there a way that I can stop the bake while retaining the information from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the escape key, should work, and should leave the bake intact up to where it was pressed.
Works on 2.81a in Windows for me.